# CSS div added to the end of the page but it dont go to the end

Tags: html, css

i am learning CSS and i am facing a problem or actually 2 problems

1 - i am trying to make all my site go center but it dont, for some reason it keep align left, i manage to make some divs go center but not all, is there a way to make all the body of the page go center ?

2 - i add divs but it hide behind header even that i am adding it at the end of the page but it dont go to the end of the page at all, ill add the CSS code and the HTML code here

here is download file of all of the site as i try to add the code but didnt work for some reason ( this is my 1st post here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6y7fihuqfs3ae3/Notify.rar?dl=0

i hope to get good help from you guys, i am sure its something small but as i said i am still learning :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting parent div.features width 80% and it is according to the page but for the child elements this width is 100% so you should set the child div width to 33.3%.
Use this CSS for div.featuresbox.
Hope this will work for you.

```
div.featuresbox {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: And to dig deep down into the CSS you should have a look to this youtube channel this could be very helpful for you. here is the link https://www.youtube.com/user/DevTipsForDesigners/playlists

Comment: Also you are using width in % and as a beginner I will recommend you to go with pixels first and then go to the % because mostly % are use when we create Responsive website designs.

Comment: but this div have nothing to do with div.featuresbox or with div.features it should be a differnet div come after them.
also i am not sure how this will fix the center issue ?

Comment: if you are talking about the div videobox and you want it to be down so you also to need add overflow:hidden to the css code 
div.features {
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: this worked but can you explain to me what this do and ?

Comment: @Adelalhajhussain It's because the floating divs doesn't have a height and floated child elements cause the parent to have 0 height, 
floating divs don't affect the size of the parent element. So that's why we are using overflow: hidden to make the element take the floating elements into consideration:

Answer (score 1):

You may center an element on the page by applying  **{margin: 0 auto;}** and also specify the width of that element.

If you don't have the width of the element specified, you need to use 
**{margin:0 auto; display:table;}** to center the element:

```css
div {margin:0 auto; display:table;}
```

```html
<div>This is centered</div>
```

The second issue you asked about most likely related to the positioning, floats and width of elements on the page.

Comment: so i use this code on the body of the page in my code or where ?
i want to center the whole page everything in it should be centered

Comment: hi, your way worked but now there is empty space on the right and the left side of the body, how i make the body go to the far end ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install firebug on firefox to check things up as you code... it helps...

to center div you need to have in css a main div that centers the divs inside of it like ccs: `#thedivid {text-align:center;}`

if your html is like : `<div id="thedivid"> <div id="the_div_i_want_to_center"></div> </div>`

that css code will center the inside div ...hope it helps

Comment: i am using class with div
also i tried to add main div but didnt work and i tried to make the body {text-align:center;} but also didnt work